# how do i get the maximum value from a hbase table from the value column?

Tags: hbase

here, i have tried to get the max valued row and its value.
instead od the standard iteration, i want to know if there exists any function

```
Scan s = new Scan();
ResultScanner re = table.getScanner(s);
int maxVal =0;         
try{
    for (Result rr = re.next(); rr != null; rr = re.next()) {
        byte [] row = rr.getRow();
        Get g = new Get(row);
        Result r = table.get(g);                   
        String rn = Bytes.toString(r.value());
        int temp = Integer.parseInt(rn);
        if(maxVal < temp)
        maxVal = temp;
    }
    System.out.println(maxVal);
}
finally {
    re.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a max() method, but it's present in "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.coprocessor". If you are OK with co-procs, then you can give it a try. It gives the maximum value of a column for a given column family for the given range. You can give the first and last column as the range here and get the max. For a detailed info on this you can go [here](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/coprocessor/AggregationClient.html#max%28byte%5B%5D,%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.ColumnInterpreter,%20org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan%29)